# Canonical form representation of a Linear Gaussian CPD

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

This question was asked in [physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81035/canonical-form-representation-of-a-linear-gaussian-cpd) but didn't get an answer and it was suggested this would be a better place. Two years later I am wondering the same thing. Here is the question with slightly different wording:

How can a linear Gaussian conditional probability distribution be represented in canonical form?

For example, let $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ be two sets of continuous variables, with $|\mathbf{X}| = n$ and $|\mathbf{Y}| = m$. Let

$p(\mathbf{Y} | \mathbf{X}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{Y} | \mathbf{a} + B\mathbf{X}; C)$

where $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector of dimension $m$, $B$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix, and $C$ is an $m$ by $m$ matrix.
How does one represent that in  canonical form?

This is boggling me particularly since a linear Gaussian is not necessarily a Gaussian probability distribution.
The canonical representation of a Gaussian has 
$K = \Sigma^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{h} = \Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu}$.
How can one have a $K$ and $\mathbf{h}$ for a something that is not a Gaussian?

Comment: Link to the question in Physics, perhaps?

Comment: Accidentally used the wrong link. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81035/canonical-form-representation-of-a-linear-gaussian-cpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer found with help from two technical reports (I can only post one link will post the other one in comments) [1], [2](http://user.it.uu.se/~thosc112/pubpdf/schonl2011.pdf).
The report from [1] only showed a univariate Gaussian. Here is my attempt at the multivariate case.

The basic idea is to use Bayes law:
$p(Y|X) = \frac{p(Y,X)}{p(X)}$

We know from [2](http://user.it.uu.se/~thosc112/pubpdf/schonl2011.pdf) that the joint of the linear Gaussian is:

$p(X,Y) = \mathcal{N} \left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\mu_X} \\
B \boldsymbol{\mu_X} + \mathbf{a}
\end{pmatrix}
, \Sigma_{X,Y} \right)$

with the process noise described by $\Sigma_{w}$ we have

$ \Sigma_{X,Y} =
\begin{pmatrix}
B^T \Sigma_{w}^{-1} B + \Sigma_{X}^{-1} & -B^T  \Sigma_{w}^{-1} \\
 -\Sigma_{w}^{-1} B &  \Sigma_{w}^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 \Sigma_{X}   &   \Sigma_{X} B^{T} \\
B \Sigma_{X} &  \Sigma_{w} + B \Sigma_{X} B^T
\end{pmatrix}$

Now to get $p(Y|X)$ we devide it py $p(X)$ which in canonical form is

$K_X = \Sigma_{X}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{h} = K_X \mu_X$

Dividing it out gives us:

$ K_{X|Y} =
\begin{pmatrix}
B^T \Sigma_{w}^{-1} B  & -B^T  \Sigma_{w}^{-1} \\
 -\Sigma_{w}^{-1} B &  \Sigma_{w}^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} $,  $\mathbf{h}_{X|Y} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, g_{X|Y} =  - \log((2 \pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma_{w}|^{1/2}) $

With $n$ the dimension of the Gaussian.

Note that I went with zero mean process noise and also assumed $\mathbf{a}$ to be zero.

The result in canonical form is probably not a valid Gaussian as $K_{X|Y}$ is probably not invertible. Multiplying it with the $p(X)$ then however gives you a valid Gaussian as one would expect.

Comment: The other report (
  [1]: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI05i6go7KAhUE7BQKHaUhCcgQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbnt.googlecode.com%2Fsvn-history%2Fr40%2Ftrunk%2FcliqueTreeImplementation2009_v0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG-UZDyVQcSuad9O4-7CvdFW06KQg&sig2=PvyxaZOY3Ii3NqvgFnblbQ)